# How do I read a cell in a google spreadsheet in google scripts targeting the spreadsheet id

Tags: google-apps-script

I need help reading a specific cell in Google scripts by using the spreadsheet id or key. I've been trying for hours without any luck. i'm using this script at the moment but it doesnt read the spreadsheet key 
`

```
function getData() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    Logger.log('Surname: ' + data[4][1]);

}
```

`

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far?  What errors are you getting or problems are you running into?

Comment: I edited the comment ^

Comment: Are you getting any messages in the console?

Comment: yes within the log I get "Surname: davids" which is in the spreadsheet

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue then, is that not the piece of data that you are trying to read?

Comment: I'm trying to get the data read via the spreadsheet key and and not an active/open spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to access a spreadsheet by ID you need to use:

```
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("abc1234567");
 Logger.log(ss.getName());
```

To get the ID, open the spreadsheet and look in the address bar of the browser.  The ID of the spreadsheet is at the end.

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/The ID is Here/edit#gid=123abc
```

Comment: Worked! Thank you soo much!!, Real life saver!